# Getting nullpointer access error while using FileReader

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file using `FileReader` but am getting null pointer access. Below is the code. Could you please tell me what the error is.

```
public class C {
    private static final String file = "a.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line1;
            while ((line1 = br2.readLine()) != null);
            {
                System.out.println(line1);
                String[] rules = line1.split(",");
                String sevkey = rules[0];
                String sevval = rules[1];
                String[] val = sevval.split("\\|");
                String actsevval = val[1];
                HashMap<String, String> sevs = new HashMap<String, String>();
                for (int i = 0; i <= sevs.size(); i++) {
                    sevs.put(sevkey, actsevval);
                    if (actsevval != "none") {
                        System.out.println(actsevval);
                    }

                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the stacktrace

Comment: The stack trace tells you.  Please read it.

Comment: `while ((line1 = br2.readLine()) != null) ;` delete the semicolon here

Comment: @DimaSan is correct, the error is that semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The code like this will work correctly:

```
public class C {
    private static final String file="a.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line1;
            while ((line1 = br2.readLine()) != null) // Here was extra semicolon!
            {
                System.out.println(line1);
                String[] rules = line1.split(",");
                String sevkey = rules[0];
                String sevval = rules[1];
                String[] val = sevval.split("\\|");
                String actsevval= val[1];
                HashMap<String, String> sevs = new HashMap<String,String>(); 
                for (int i =0; i<=sevs.size();i++){
                    sevs.put(sevkey, actsevval);
                    if (actsevval!="none"){
                        System.out.println(actsevval);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```